# Issue with getting Local Storage values in Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

I'm using the following JQuery code to get values with numeric keys from the Local Storage.

```
$.each(localStorage, function(key, val)
{
    if($.isNumeric(key))
    {
        console.log(key + ", " + val);
    }
});
```

I have consequentially added the values with keys "1", "2" and "3" to Local Storage.  But the loop above prints the values in the keys' back order in Firefox, i.e., "3", "2", "1".  If I run this script on Chrome and IE, the values are printed in the expected order ("1", "2", "3").

All the browsers are updated to latest versions (FF - 25.0.1, Chrome - 31.0.1650.57, IE - 11).

Could someone help me to understand why the FF returns the values in back order and how can I prevent this?  Surely, I can assign the values of Local Storage to some array and then sort it, but I would like to avoid extra coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When keys are added to the localStorage they are added to a map. Unfortunatelly there is no guarantee that this map will have a given order when you iterate through it. It will depend on the browser implementation hence difference between Chrome/IE vs FF. What you can do to solve your issue is something like that :

```
var keys = Object.keys(localStorage);
var sortedKeys = keys.sort();
$.each(.sort(), function(key, val)
{
    if($.isNumeric(key))
    {
        console.log(key + ", " + val);
    }
});
```

but this will not preserve the order of addition to the localStorage map it will only sort the key by lexical order. If needed you can modify the above code and add a custom sort function.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas ABRIC, it worked! I have only changed "$.each(.sort(), function(key, val)" to "$.each(sortedKeys, function(key, val)" :)

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is just key-value dictionary. It doesn't support ordering. If you want to sort items in some order take a look at following links:

[Html5 local storage sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959817/html5-local-storage-sort)

[javascript html5 localstorage sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047851/javascript-html5-local-storage-sort-order)