# localStorage sort order by value

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I've put some data in localStorage, and I want to retrieve to key names in an array, ordered by the value:

France : 0
Italy: 1
England: 2
Germany: 3
.. etc.

```
function getCountries() {
    "use strict";
    var returnArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        returnArray.push(localStorage.key(i));
    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

Right now the order of the key-names in the array seems to be quite random - how to order the array by the values?

Comment: Have you looked at this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959817/html5-local-storage-sort

Comment: You could put the entire array as JSON in one entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort in multiple places you can create a prototype.

```
Array.prototype.sortOnValue = function(key){
    this.sort(function(a, b){
        if(a[key] < b[key]){
            return -1;
        }else if(a[key] > b[key]){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qj16bwq/2/) of how to use it.

Comment: Very useful help! I'm not familier with this setup - how do I retrieve the country name from a place en the array? If i alert arr[0] i'll get [Object object] ?

Comment: Works perfectly now - I'll just add that there's missing a parseInt around the a[key] and b[key] in the above for it to work correctly ;)

Comment: @TheSimon, thanks ill update my fiddle and code, i was not sure if your value was a string or int.

Answer (score 0):

```
var countries = Object
    .keys(localStorage)
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return localStorage[a] - localStorage[b];
    })
```