# Add item at beginning of array on completion

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Almost finished (finally) building a simple to do list.

I'm trying to improve what I've done so far.

One big issue is if say you add a task for e.g. 'Task 1' and then 'Task 2' naturally the array will hold them in that order.

The problem with that is if you 'complete' say Task 2 and then 'uncomplete' it goes back to the top of the list.

But I'm using local storage to save my data so even though it goes to the top of the list on the front end when you refresh it doesn't stay there because in the array it is in position 2.

I'm aware of the 'unshift' method but not sure how to use it here in my completed/uncompleted task methods.

Essentially I want my tasks that go from complete back to uncomplete to be priority and go to the top of the uncompleted task list and thus save that order in my local storage array.

https://jsfiddle.net/1uopkysn/

Thanks

JS

```
// To do list

var storeToDos = [];

// Cache DOM
var addToDo = document.getElementById('add-to-do');
var taskHolder = document.getElementById('task-holder');
var uncompleteTasks = document.getElementById('uncompleted-tasks');
var completedTasks = document.getElementById('completed-tasks');

// Bind events
var bindEvents = function(listItem, checkboxEventHandler) {
  // Delete
  var deleteToDo = listItem.querySelector('.delete-to-do');
  deleteToDo.addEventListener('click', deleteTask);
  // Edit
  listItem.querySelector('.edit-to-do').addEventListener('click', editTask);
  listItem.querySelector('.edit-holder').addEventListener('keyup', editTaskEnter);
  // Checkbox
  var checkbox = listItem.querySelector('input.edit-to-do');
  checkbox.onchange = checkboxEventHandler;
}

// Create list item
var createListItem = function() {
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  var deleteToDo = document.createElement('div');
  deleteToDo.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7.1 7.1l9.8 9.8M7.1 16.9l9.8-9.8"/></svg>';
  deleteToDo.classList.add('delete-to-do');
  var editToDo = document.createElement('div');
  editToDo.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path fill="none" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16 3l5 5L8 21H3v-5z"/></svg>';
  editToDo.classList.add('edit-to-do');
  var toDoStatus = document.createElement('input');
  toDoStatus.type = 'checkbox';
  toDoStatus.classList.add('edit-to-do');
  var editHolder = document.createElement('input');
  editHolder.type = 'text';
  editHolder.classList.add('edit-holder');

  listItem.appendChild(deleteToDo);
  listItem.appendChild(editToDo);
  listItem.appendChild(toDoStatus);
  listItem.appendChild(editHolder);

  return listItem;
}

// Add task
var addTask = function(e) {
  var listItem = createListItem();
  var taskHolderValue = taskHolder.value;
  if(taskHolderValue) {
    var taskHolderElement = document.createElement('label');
    taskHolderElement.classList.add('to-do-item');
    listItem.insertBefore(taskHolderElement, listItem.childNodes[0]);
    var storeToDosObj = {
      value: '',
      id: null,
      completed: false
    }
    storeToDosObj.value = taskHolderValue;
    var listId = storeToDosObj.id = Date.now();
    listItem.id = listId;
    uncompleteTasks.insertBefore(listItem, uncompleteTasks.childNodes[0]);
    var storedToDos = localStorage.getItem('todos');
    if(storedToDos) {
      var storedToDosArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.todos);
      storedToDosArr.push(storeToDosObj);
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedToDosArr));
    } else {
      console.log(storeToDos);
      storeToDos.push(storeToDosObj);
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storeToDos));
    }
    taskHolderElement.innerHTML = taskHolderValue;
    bindEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);
    taskHolder.value = '';
  } else {
    alert("You didn't add a to a to do!");
  }
}

var addTaskEnter = function(e) {
  var key = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if(key === 13) {
    addTask();
  }
}

// Delete task
var deleteTask = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  var parentItem = listItem.parentNode;
  var getToDos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
  for(var b=0; b<getToDos.length; b++) {
    if(getToDos[b].id == listItem.id) {
      getToDos.splice(b, 1);
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(getToDos));
    }
  }
  parentItem.removeChild(listItem);
}

// Edit task
var editTask = function() {
  var defaultValue = this.parentNode.querySelector('label').innerHTML;
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  var listParent = this.parentNode;
  var editedValue = listParent.querySelector('input.edit-holder').value;
  if(listItem.classList.contains('editing') && editedValue) {
    listParent.querySelector('label').innerHTML = editedValue;
    var storedLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.todos);
    for(var d=0; d<storedLocalStorage.length; d++) {
      if(storedLocalStorage[d].id == listItem.id) {
        storedLocalStorage[d].value = editedValue;
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedLocalStorage));
      }
    }
  }
  listItem.classList.toggle('editing');
  listParent.querySelector('input.edit-holder').value = '';
}

// Edit task enter
var editTaskEnter = function(e) {
  var key = 'which' in e ? e.which : e.keyCode;
  if(key === 13) {
    editTask.call(this);
  }
}

// Task completed
var taskCompleted = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;

  var storedCompletion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
  if(storedCompletion) {
    if(listItem.classList.contains('editing')) {

    }
    for(var e=0; e<storedCompletion.length; e++) {
      if(storedCompletion[e].id == listItem.id) {
        if(storedCompletion[e].completed === true) {
          this.parentNode.classList.add('completed');
          uncompleteTasks.insertBefore(listItem, uncompleteTasks.childNodes[0]);
          this.parentNode.classList.remove('completed');
          bindEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);
          storedCompletion[e].completed = false;
        } else {
          completedTasks.insertBefore(listItem, completedTasks.childNodes[0]);
          this.parentNode.classList.add('completed');
          bindEvents(listItem, taskUncompleted);
          storedCompletion[e].completed = true;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedCompletion));
      }
    }
  }
}

// Task uncompleted
var taskUncompleted = function() {
  var listItem = this.parentNode;
  uncompleteTasks.insertBefore(listItem, uncompleteTasks.childNodes[0]);
  this.parentNode.classList.remove('completed');
  bindEvents(listItem, taskCompleted);

  if(localStorage) {
    var storedCompletion = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
  }

  for(var f=0; f<storedCompletion.length; f++) {
    if(storedCompletion[f].id == listItem.id) {
      storedCompletion[f].completed = false;
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(storedCompletion));
    }
  }
}

// Add task
addToDo.addEventListener("click", addTask);
taskHolder.addEventListener("keyup", addTaskEnter);

// Loop over complete tasks
for(i=0; i<completedTasks.length; i++) {
  var listItem = completedTasks[i];
  uncompleteTasks.appendChild(listItem);
  bindEvents(listItem, completedTasks);
}

// Render local storage
var getToDos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
console.log(getToDos);
if(getToDos) {
  for(i=0; i<getToDos.length; i++) {
    var listItem = createListItem();
    listItem.id = getToDos[i].id;
    var storedListItem = document.createElement('label');
    storedListItem.innerHTML = getToDos[i].value;
    listItem.insertBefore(storedListItem, listItem.childNodes[0]);
    if(getToDos[i].completed === true) {
      listItem.querySelector('input').checked = true;
      completedTasks.appendChild(listItem);
      listItem.classList.add('completed');
    } else {
      uncompleteTasks.appendChild(listItem);
    }
    bindEvents(listItem, taskCompleted)
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider making `todos` an object that contains 2 arrays : `{completed:[], incomplete:[]}` ... or use `splice()` to move an item in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate timestamps with the items and display them according to timestamps in both completed and uncompleted lists. There is no sorting method in LocalStorage though, likewise you cannot insert before or after specifically.

You can sort the array retrieved from json like this (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38808128/5213405)). you can use timestamp to sort array -
JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1uopkysn/).

```
Array.prototype.sortOnValue = function(key){
    this.sort(function(a, b){
        if(a[key] < b[key]){
            return -1;
        }else if(a[key] > b[key]){
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
}

var arr = [{country:'France', value:'0'},{country:'Italy', value:'3'},
{country:'England', value:'1'},
{country:'Germany', value:'2'}];


arr.sortOnValue("value");

console.log(arr);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How about updating the stored array when you change something in memory?
So each time you make a change to your view, you update the "model", thus the JSON array and save it again.